# How to get the last X modified files from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have in our bucket lots of keys (zipped).

we want to request from s3 only the last X keys that were created.

We use Java API. However, I couldn't find a way how to get only last modified/created.

We have sorted the list ourselves but still, we don't get the last X items. that's problematic as this bucket can be huge and we don't want to retrieve all results and sort them.

```
public List<MyObject> getResults(int numberOfResults) {
        ObjectListing listing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName)
                .withMaxKeys(numberOfResults));
        List<S3ObjectSummary> list = listing.getObjectSummaries();

// our internal sorting logic:

        List<MyObject> myObjects = list.stream().map(item ->
              MyObject.builder().resultKey(item.getKey()).createdDate(item.getLastModified()).build()).sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getCreatedDate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return myObjects;
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: How does files get updated and uploaded? is it ONLY through that same Java app?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this same challenge and was able to use the following command to get information from S3 API:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --max-items 3 --query "reverse(sort_by(Contents,&LastModified))" --bucket <bucketName>
```

You could adjust `--max-items` to the `X` you need.

I hope that becomes helpful to others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I think Aws is not offering a way to do this in server side. You can use the client side filtering. By CLI you can do this like `aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketName --query "sort_by(keys,LastModified)"`

Comment: if I do client side filtering i might get out-of-memory if I have lots of files eventually, no? how can I use cli via java?

Comment: You can use java ProcessBuilder to call CLI command `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( command );
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        } `

Comment: `list-objects` will take `Contents` and not `keys` as a sort param